# Display partialview when clicking a link

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm fairly new to JQuery and MVC 2 which makes this a bit harder, I've always used WebForms before.
I'm using the [NerdDinner](http://nerddinner.codeplex.com/) example as setup (I've switched *Dinner* for *Person* though).
What I want to do is pretty simple.  In a table I want a small modal display with details when a "details" link is clicked in the table.
Right now when I click a link I open "Details.ascx" in a new window, it's not adding it to the details div

**Search page** (View)

Link in table: (foreach (var item in Model))

```
<%= Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id}, new AjaxOptions() { UpdateTargetId = "details" })%>
```

javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('tr').click(function() {
        $("#details").load("Persons/Details/1")
    });
</script>
```

div to contain details:

```
<div id="details" class="detailView">details here</div>
```

Partialview:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<Person>" %>
<%@ Import namespace="RegistryTest.Models" %>
<div id="detailsModal">
    <%= Html.Encode(Model.surname) %>
</div>
```

**Controllers**

```
public PartialViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        Person person = repository.GetPerson(id);

        return PartialView("Details", person);
    }
```

Let me know if you need more info on the setup.

Comment: http://blog.dmbcllc.com/2008/12/30/jquery-loading-partial-content/ <<<=== that what you mean ?

Comment: Yes exactly, loading a ascx partial view into a div. It's not working though.

Comment: Im sorry im not a fun of asp it might aswell be a chinese to me so I simplified it for you so can understand how it works on my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignore the `Ajax` helpers, they're for ASP.NET AJAX scripting.

Change your link to:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.id})%>
```

And your jQuery to:

```
    $('tr').click(function() {
        var url = jQuery(this).find('a').attr('href');
        $("#details").load(url)
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

**page1.asp**

```
<div class="holder">
    <div>1</div>
    <div class="test">2</div>
</div>
```

$('.holder').load('page1.asp .test');// returns =>> 2
// .test grabs any element that has a .test and pushes it into the holder

so page would look like this...

```
<div class="holder">
    <div class="test">2</div>
</div>
```